# Do MySQL transaction commits apply queries, or results?

Tags: mysql, concurrency, transactions

If I start a transaction, run some queries, and then commit it, does the commit work by applying the results of the queries, or the queries themselves?

For instance, if my transaction contains `insert into b select x from a`, and the x changes after I run this query but before I commit the transaction, will the result be the value of x as it was during the transaction, or the value of x at the time of the commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:** `x` will have the value that it had at the timestamp of read.

To be more specific, commit is a part of the transaction, so you may not address it as *during the transaction or at the time of commit*, they are not two separate operation.

**Clarification:** Using transaction will ensure that all the operations within the transaction boundaries look **atomic** to outside world.

Atomic operation means that:

- The operation should be either succeed or fail. There must not be an intermediary step in between. In particular, if a transaction starts and a failure (like power outage) occurs, it needs to rollback all the changes that it has made so far.
- Also it means that outside world should see it as a single operation. If a transaction uses some values, all the values should be taken from the timestamp right at the start of the transaction. Similarly all the changes that transaction should make, will be available to outside world right after the timestamp at which the transaction ends. This is achieved by proper form of locking (exclusive, read or write) tables involved in the transaction.

So to be more specific regarding your question, when `select x from a` is called in a transaction, table `a` is locked till the transaction either commits or rolled back. The scenario you mentioned, *x changes after I run this query* (before transaction commits/rolled back), **is not practically possible** .

Comment: So when the select is called, it both reads the value at that time, and locks the table so that it can't be changed until the transaction commits? You're saying that all selects inside a transaction lock the table until the transaction completes?

Comment: @Benubird Yes, we can mostly conclude that way. All the READs in a transaction will make a WRITE lock on the tables they used, so outside world cannot WRITE to those table but they are free to READ from. On the other side if a transaction WRITEs to a table, then that table is locked for both READ and WRITE to outside world.